# write xml file from data table ignoring columns with white spaces

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datatable

I am trying to export the data from a data table into  xml file.  I have this part working but when a record does not have any data or a white space it  still writes the it in the  xml file   with XML:space Preserved.

I want to ignore the columns and not have them in xml file if they do not have any data in them

example of the xml file it is producing now

[image: this is the current output]

I want customer street 3 and 4 nodes to be not printed if they don't have any values in them.

here is my code

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using System.Xml;

namespace InvoicePrintProgram
{
   class XMLGenerator
   {
    //Defining method that generates  XMl Files
    public void Start(String XmlFilepath, string XMlFileName, DataTable DT, int PageCountOut, int SequenceCountOut, int[] PrefIndex/*, int[] SequenceIndex, IEnumerable<String> chunk, int IndexCount out int IndexCountOut*/)
    {
        // Creates Xml file from datatable using the wrtieXml method 

        FileStream streamWrite = new FileStream(XmlFilepath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);

        System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings settings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        //settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1") 
        settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        settings.CloseOutput = true;
        settings.CheckCharacters = true;
        settings.NewLineChars = "\r\n";

        DT.WriteXml(streamWrite, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
```

Comment: Not sure how code your posted is related to question. Also would you mind to clean up sample so it have no unrelated code/white space? Please also clarify what part of checking value for not being empty causes you problem.

Comment: cleaned up the code as requested.  I am looking to see how  I can not print the customer address 3 and 4 if there no data in the  column for a record .

Comment: Looks better now - thanks. I don't think you can configure DataTable to do what you want, but I have very little experience with that class - so hopefully there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a List of Object from that DataTable and use something like this:

```
List<string> xml_string = new List<string>();
xml_string.Add("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>");
xml_string.Add("anything you need as header");
foreach(string current_string in your_object_of_DataTable)
{


 if(current_string!=null || current_string.Trim()!="")
    {
      xml_string.Add("<Your Tag>"+current_string+"</Your Tag>");
    }
}
 try
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\xml_file_name.xml"))
                {
                    foreach (string line in xml_string)
                    {
                        file.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File exported.");
            }
```